# PHP form not sending all information via email

Tags: php

On my website I have a form that calls a PHP script when send is clicked.  It will send me an email but, if I fill out all of the blocks on the form it sends only a blank email or only showing one or two boxes filled out.  The main thing I noticed is the name is missing even though it's filled out when all the blocks are filled out.  Here is the php code for sending the form. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
$msg =$_POST['WSD-Name'];
$msg2=$_POST['WSD-Phone'];
$msg3=$_POST['WSD-Email'];
$msg4=$_POST['WSD-Address'];
$msg5=$_POST['WSD-City'];
$msg6=$_POST['WSD-ZIP'];
$msg7=$_POST['WSD-DOB'];
$msg8=$_POST['WSD-Fitness-Level'];
$to='example@servertest.com';
$subject='Wsd application';

mail($to,$subject,$msg8,$msg7,$msg6,$msg5,$msg4,$msg3,$msg2,$msg);
echo 'Thanks for the submission.';
```

Comment: That's not how `mail()` works. Read the manual to see how to use it properly.

Comment: See how [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) works.

Comment: Can you give me more guidance.  As you can tell and pointed out, I am beginning at this...

Comment: Reading the manual *is* guidance. It shows you *exactly* how to do this.

Comment: @Jamesb2 [Here is a basic php mail() tutorial for you...](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't do that.
Do this instead

```
$emailMessage = $msg.",".$msg2.",".$msg3.",".$msg4.",".$msg5.",".$msg6.",".$msg7.",".$msg8;
mail($to,$subject,$emailMessage);
```